# TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, naivebayes, multinomial

I'm trying to make multinomial naive bayes classifier without using SKlearn MNB.

Here's the code for the classifier :

```
class MultinomialNaiveBayes:

def __init__(self):
    # count is a dictionary which stores several dictionaries corresponding to each news category
    # each value in the subdictionary represents the freq of the key corresponding to that news category 
    self.count = {}
    # classes represents the different news categories
    self.classes = None

def fit(self,X_train,Y_train):
    # This can take some time to complete       
    self.classes = set(Y_train)
    for class_ in self.classes:
        self.count[class_] = {}
        for i in range(len(X_train[0])):
            self.count[class_][i] = 0
        self.count[class_]['total'] = 0
        self.count[class_]['total_points'] = 0
    self.count['total_points'] = len(X_train)

    for i in range(len(X_train)):
        for j in range(len(X_train[0])):
            self.count[Y_train[i]][j]+=X_train[i][j]
            self.count[Y_train[i]]['total']+=X_train[i][j]
        self.count[Y_train[i]]['total_points']+=1

def __probability(self,test_point,class_):

    log_prob = np.log(self.count[class_]['total_points']) - np.log(self.count['total_points'])
    total_words = len(test_point)
    for i in range(len(test_point)):
        current_word_prob = test_point[i]*(np.log(self.count[class_][i]+1)-np.log(self.count[class_]['total']+total_words))
        log_prob += current_word_prob

    return log_prob


def __predictSinglePoint(self,test_point):

    best_class = None
    best_prob = None
    first_run = True

    for class_ in self.classes:
        log_probability_current_class = self.__probability(test_point,class_)
        if (first_run) or (log_probability_current_class > best_prob) :
            best_class = class_
            best_prob = log_probability_current_class
            first_run = False

    return best_class


def predict(self,X_test):
    # This can take some time to complete
    Y_pred = [] 
    for i in range(X_test.size):
    # print(i) # Uncomment to see progress
        Y_pred.append( self.__predictSinglePoint(X_test[i]) )

    return Y_pred

def score(self,Y_pred,Y_true):
    # returns the mean accuracy
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(Y_pred)):
        if Y_pred[i] == Y_true[i]:
            count+=1
    return count/len(Y_pred)
```

However, when i try to fit training data to this model, there is an error like this.

> TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]

then i try to change my train data to dense array. But that resulted an error like this.

> IndexError: too many indices for array

What should i do ? i did preprocessing using tfidf vectorizer for my train data, so my train data look like this.

```
(0, 3838)   0.3188116041495794
(0, 1314)   0.47611391519517965
(0, 3852)   0.6748521310739798
(0, 4460)   0.46502613045074925
(1, 2997)   0.5124730713021854
(1, 7283)   0.37699134972197723
(1, 7363)   0.29325712956005184
(1, 3226)   0.3049856710575078
(1, 7461)   0.44783186231025657
(1, 2275)   0.3687679018146693
(1, 3308)   0.28229369020160777
```

I'm sorry if my question is duplicate because i still dont get the solution for this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace any `len()` call on the `X_train`, A.K.A, the sparse matrix, in your code with `shape[0]`, for example:

```
def fit(self,X_train,Y_train):
    # This can take some time to complete       
    self.classes = set(Y_train)
    for class_ in self.classes:
        self.count[class_] = {}
        for i in range(X_train[0].shape[0]):
            self.count[class_][i] = 0
        self.count[class_]['total'] = 0
        self.count[class_]['total_points'] = 0
    self.count['total_points'] = X_train.shape[0]

    for i in range(X_train.shape[0]):
        for j in range(X_train[0].shape[0]):
            self.count[Y_train[i]][j]+=X_train[i][j]
            self.count[Y_train[i]]['total']+=X_train[i][j]
        self.count[Y_train[i]]['total_points']+=1
```